# Aplicación Lentísima: "the application may be doing too much work on its main thread"

Tags: java, android, firebase, android-asynctask, android-sqlite

Al lanzar mi aplicación, me sale el mensaje que ya conoceréis:

> the application may be doing too much work on its main thread.

Investigando para solucionar ello me encontré con que hay que usar subprocesos ya que en mi código, todo lo estoy realizando sobre un solo proceso y es cierto.

El problema es que no sé como poner las lineas de código en otros subprocesos, ya que mi código está organizado de esta manera:

```
public View onCreateView(LayoutInflater inflater, ViewGroup container,
                         Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    View view = inflater.inflate(R.layout.fragment_contenido_one, container, false);


    //componentes visuales
    promoHeader = (RecyclerView) view.findViewById(R.id.promo_header);
    resTotal = (RecyclerView) view.findViewById(R.id.res_total);
    resCat = (RecyclerView) view.findViewById(R.id.res_cat);


    //Lista de las url de las promos de restaurante para el header
    resHeaderListUrl = new ArrayList<>();
    resHeaderListUrl = selectColumFrom(SQLDataBase.DatosTabla.PROMO_COLUMNA_IMAGE_URL, SQLDataBase.DatosTabla.TABLA_PROMOS);

    //TEST: ORDER
    resListUrl = new ArrayList<>();
    resListUrl = orden(SQLDataBase.DatosTabla.RES_COLUMNA_IMAGE_URL, SQLDataBase.DatosTabla.TABLA_RES, SQLDataBase.DatosTabla.RES_COLUMNA_LIKE_COUNT, "DESC", "yes");


    //Lista de los nombres de restaurantes para el content
    resListName = new ArrayList<>();
    resListName = orden(SQLDataBase.DatosTabla.RES_COLUMNA_NOMBRE, SQLDataBase.DatosTabla.TABLA_RES, SQLDataBase.DatosTabla.RES_COLUMNA_LIKE_COUNT, "DESC", "yes");

    resListCatUrl = new ArrayList<>();
    resListCatUrl = categoria(SQLDataBase.DatosTabla.RES_COLUMNA_IMAGE_URL, "meat");

    resListCatName = new ArrayList<>();
    resListCatName = categoria(SQLDataBase.DatosTabla.RES_COLUMNA_NOMBRE, "meat");


    //Adaptadores header y content
    headerAdapter = new HeaderHorizontalAdapter(resHeaderListUrl);
    contentAdapterRes = new ContentHorizontalAdapter(resListName, resListUrl);
    categoryAdapter = new CategoryHorizontalAdapter(resListCatName, resListCatUrl);


    //set del manager layout header y content
    LinearLayoutManager promoResLayoutManager
            = new LinearLayoutManager(getActivity(), LinearLayoutManager.HORIZONTAL, false);
    promoHeader.setLayoutManager(promoResLayoutManager);

    LinearLayoutManager contentResLayoutManager
            = new LinearLayoutManager(getActivity(), LinearLayoutManager.HORIZONTAL, false);
    resTotal.setLayoutManager(contentResLayoutManager);

    LinearLayoutManager categoryResLayoutManager
            = new LinearLayoutManager(getActivity(), LinearLayoutManager.HORIZONTAL, false);
    resCat.setLayoutManager(categoryResLayoutManager);

    //set de los adaptadores header y content
    promoHeader.setAdapter(headerAdapter);
    resTotal.setAdapter(contentAdapterRes);
    resCat.setAdapter(categoryAdapter);

    return view;
}


@Override
public void onFragmentInteraction(Uri uri) {

}

public class ContentHorizontalAdapter extends RecyclerView.Adapter<ContentHorizontalAdapter.MyViewHolder> {

    private List<String> listName;
    private List<String> listImg;

    public class MyViewHolder extends RecyclerView.ViewHolder {
        public TextView txtView;
        public ImageView imgView;

        public MyViewHolder(View view) {
            super(view);
            txtView = (TextView) view.findViewById(R.id.txt_res_item);
            imgView = (ImageView) view.findViewById(R.id.img_res_item);
        }
    }


    public ContentHorizontalAdapter(List<String> horizontalList, List<String> horizontalListImg) {
        this.listName = horizontalList;
        this.listImg = horizontalListImg;
    }


    @Override
    public MyViewHolder onCreateViewHolder(ViewGroup parent, final int viewType) {
        final View itemView = LayoutInflater.from(parent.getContext())
                .inflate(R.layout.item_horizontal1, parent, false);

        return new MyViewHolder(itemView);
    }


    @Override
    public void onBindViewHolder(final MyViewHolder holder, final int position) {
        //Carga de imagen sin descargar archivo.
        Picasso p = Picasso.with(getActivity());
        p.setIndicatorsEnabled(true);
        /*Picasso.with(getActivity())*/
        p.load(listImg.get(position))
                .into(holder.imgView, new Callback() {
                    @Override
                    public void onSuccess() {
                        picassoLoad++;
                        if (picassoLoad == (listImg.size() - 1)) {
                            splashHomeLoad.setVisibility(View.GONE);
                            picassoLoad = 0;

                        }
                    }

                    @Override
                    public void onError() {

                    }
                });

        //set del nombre de res
        holder.txtView.setText(listName.get(position));


        holder.imgView.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {

            @Override
            public void onClick(View view) {
                idRes = selectId(SQLDataBase.DatosTabla.RES_COLUMNA_ID, SQLDataBase.DatosTabla.TABLA_RES, listImg.get(position));
                urlHeaderSelected = listImg.get(position);

                Fragment local = new LocalSeleccionado();
                fm = getFragmentManager();
                fragmentTransaction = fm.beginTransaction();
                fragmentTransaction.replace(R.id.fragment_holder, local);
                fragmentTransaction.addToBackStack(null);
                fragmentTransaction.commit();
            }
        });
    }

    @Override
    public int getItemCount() {
        return listName.size();
    }
}


public class CategoryHorizontalAdapter extends RecyclerView.Adapter<CategoryHorizontalAdapter.MyViewHolder> {

    private List<String> listNameCat;
    private List<String> listImgCat;

    public class MyViewHolder extends RecyclerView.ViewHolder {
        public TextView txtViewCat;
        public ImageView imgViewCat;

        public MyViewHolder(View view) {
            super(view);
            txtViewCat = (TextView) view.findViewById(R.id.txt_res_cat_item);
            imgViewCat = (ImageView) view.findViewById(R.id.img_res_cat_item);
        }
    }


    public CategoryHorizontalAdapter(List<String> horizontalListName, List<String> horizontalListImg) {
        this.listNameCat = horizontalListName;
        this.listImgCat = horizontalListImg;
    }


    @Override
    public MyViewHolder onCreateViewHolder(ViewGroup parent, final int viewType) {
        final View itemView = LayoutInflater.from(parent.getContext())
                .inflate(R.layout.res_cat_veg, parent, false);

        return new MyViewHolder(itemView);
    }


    @Override
    public void onBindViewHolder(final MyViewHolder holder, final int position) {
        //Carga de imagen sin descargar archivo.
        Picasso p = Picasso.with(getActivity());
        p.setIndicatorsEnabled(true);
        /*Picasso.with(getActivity())*/
        p.load(listImgCat.get(position))
                .into(holder.imgViewCat, new Callback() {
                    @Override
                    public void onSuccess() {
                        //picassoLoad++;
                        if (picassoLoad == (listImgCat.size() - 1)) {
                            splashHomeLoad.setVisibility(View.GONE);
                            picassoLoad = 0;

                        }
                    }

                    @Override
                    public void onError() {

                    }
                });

        //set del nombre de res
        holder.txtViewCat.setText(listNameCat.get(position));
        holder.imgViewCat.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {

            @Override
            public void onClick(View view) {
                idRes = selectId(SQLDataBase.DatosTabla.RES_COLUMNA_ID, SQLDataBase.DatosTabla.TABLA_RES, listImgCat.get(position));
                urlHeaderSelected = listImgCat.get(position);

                Fragment local = new LocalSeleccionado();
                fm = getFragmentManager();
                fragmentTransaction = fm.beginTransaction();
                fragmentTransaction.replace(R.id.fragment_holder, local);
                fragmentTransaction.addToBackStack(null);
                fragmentTransaction.commit();
            }
        });
    }

    @Override
    public int getItemCount() {
        return listNameCat.size();
    }
}


public class HeaderHorizontalAdapter extends RecyclerView.Adapter<HeaderHorizontalAdapter.MyViewHolder> {

    private List<String> headerList;

    public class MyViewHolder extends RecyclerView.ViewHolder {
        public ImageView imgPromo;

        public MyViewHolder(View view) {
            super(view);
            imgPromo = (ImageView) view.findViewById(R.id.img_res_promo);
        }
    }


    public HeaderHorizontalAdapter(List<String> headerList) {
        this.headerList = headerList;
    }

    @Override
    public MyViewHolder onCreateViewHolder(ViewGroup parent, int viewType) {
        View itemView = LayoutInflater.from(parent.getContext())
                .inflate(R.layout.header_images, parent, false);

        return new MyViewHolder(itemView);
    }


    @Override
    public void onBindViewHolder(final MyViewHolder holder, final int position) {
        Picasso.with(getActivity()).load(headerList.get(position)).into(holder.imgPromo);

        holder.imgPromo.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
            @Override
            public void onClick(View v) {

                dbRead = BBDD.getWritableDatabase();
                String[] buscar = {headerList.get(position)};
                String[] result = {SQLDataBase.DatosTabla.PROMO_COLUMNA_NOMBRE};
                Cursor c = dbRead.query(SQLDataBase.DatosTabla.TABLA_PROMOS, result, SQLDataBase.DatosTabla.PROMO_COLUMNA_IMAGE_URL + "=?", buscar, null, null, null);

                if (c.moveToFirst()) {
                    String p = c.getString(0);
                    //barRelativeInfo.setText(p);

                    Toast.makeText(getActivity(), c.getString(0),
                            Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
                }
                c.close();
            }
        });

    }

    @Override
    public int getItemCount() {
        return headerList.size();
    }
}


//obtener
public List<String> selectColumFrom(String column, String tableName) {
    List<String> rows = new ArrayList<>();
    db = BBDD.getWritableDatabase();
    String[] result = {column};
    Cursor rowsResults = db.query(tableName, result, null, null, null, null, null);
    if (rowsResults.moveToFirst()) {
        do {
            rows.add(rowsResults.getString(0));
        } while (rowsResults.moveToNext());
    }

    db.close();
    rowsResults.close();

    return rows;
}

public List<String> orden(String column, String tableName, String orderBy, String mode, String rank) {
    List<String> rows = new ArrayList<>();
    db = BBDD.getWritableDatabase();
    String[] result = {column};

    Cursor rowsResults;

    if (rank.equals("yes")) {
        rowsResults = db.query(tableName, result, null, null, null, null, orderBy + " " + mode + " LIMIT " + topRank);
    } else {
        rowsResults = db.query(tableName, result, null, null, null, null, orderBy + " " + mode);
    }


    if (rowsResults.moveToFirst()) {
        do {
            rows.add(rowsResults.getString(0));
        } while (rowsResults.moveToNext());
    }

    db.close();
    rowsResults.close();

    return rows;
}

//añadir un orderBy para controlar el rank tambien
//public List<String> categoria(String column, String tableName, String cat) {
public List<String> categoria(String column, String cat) {
    List<String> rowsId = new ArrayList<>();
    List<String> rows = new ArrayList<>();

    db = BBDD.getWritableDatabase();
    String[] result = {column};
    String[] condition = {cat};
    //Cursor rowsResults=db.query(tableName,);
    Cursor rowsResults = db.rawQuery("SELECT DISTINCT id FROM restaurantes WHERE id in" +
            "(SELECT id_res FROM platos WHERE id_cat=?)", condition);
    if (rowsResults.moveToFirst()) {
        do {
            rowsId.add(rowsResults.getString(0));
        } while (rowsResults.moveToNext());
        rowsResults.close();

        for (int i = 0; i < rowsId.size(); i++) {
            String[] id = {rowsId.get(i)};
            Cursor rowsFinals = db.query("restaurantes", result, "id=?", id, null, null, null);
            rowsFinals.moveToFirst();
            rows.add(rowsFinals.getString(0));
            rowsFinals.close();
        }
    }

    return rows;

}

//id del restaurante para cargar sus platos (tienen una relacion 'pertenece') en un fragment
public String selectId(String column, String tableName, String where) {
    db = BBDD.getWritableDatabase();
    String[] buscar = {where};
    String[] result = {column};
    Cursor rowId = db.query(tableName, result, SQLDataBase.DatosTabla.RES_COLUMNA_IMAGE_URL + "=?", buscar, null, null, null);

    rowId.moveToFirst();
    String aux = rowId.getString(0);
    rowId.close();
    return aux;
}
```

También esta clase adaptador:

```
public View onCreateView(LayoutInflater inflater, ViewGroup container,
                         Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    View view = inflater.inflate(R.layout.fragment_local_seleccionado, container, false);
    // Inflate the layout for this fragment
    splashResLoad = (RelativeLayout) view.findViewById(R.id.splash_res_load);
    splashResLoad.setVisibility(View.VISIBLE);

    headerLocalSelected = (ImageView) view.findViewById(R.id.local_selected);
    gridview = (GridView) view.findViewById(R.id.grid_items);// crear el


    Picasso.with(getActivity()).load(urlHeaderSelected).into(headerLocalSelected);
    gridview.setAdapter(new AdaptadorFoods(container.getContext()));// con setAdapter se llena
    gridview.setOnItemClickListener(new AdapterView.OnItemClickListener() {

        public void onItemClick(AdapterView<?> parent, View v,
                                int position, long id) {

            TextView auxKey = (TextView) v.findViewById(R.id.name_food);

            //lanzamos dialog
            final Dialog information = new Dialog(getActivity());
            information.setContentView(R.layout.info_item_food);
            // information.setTitle("Perfe");

            ImageView info_img = (ImageView) information.findViewById(R.id.info_food_image);
            TextView info_text = (TextView) information.findViewById(R.id.info_food_text);

            //Food temp = foods.get(position);

            Picasso.with(getActivity()).load(foodUrl.get(position)).into(info_img);
            String info = descripcion(SQLDataBase.DatosTabla.PLATO_COLUMNA_DESC, SQLDataBase.DatosTabla.TABLA_PLATOS, foodUrl.get(position));
            info_text.setText(info);
            information.setTitle("getNanmeFromDDBB");

            information.show();
            info_img.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
                @Override
                public void onClick(View view) {
                    information.dismiss();
                }
            });

        }
    });

    return view;
}
```

Sólo quiero saber como hacer el subproceso, ya que ahora mismo la aplicación va lentísimo y es imposible navegar sobre ella.
Muchas Gracias.

Comment: No asumas que la causa es debida a que haces todo en un mismo proceso, ya que puede deberse a otras cosas y aunque uses subprocesos, si el código no está optimizado, seguirás teniendo el mismo problema. Si estás haciendo consultas a la base de datos, verifica que la misma tenga los índices bien creados, que no estés llamando demasiados datos innecesarios (un ejemplo típico de esto son los `SELECT * ...` cuando sólo se necesitan algunos campos específicos de la tabla. Verifica las llamadas o procesos que haces dentro de los bucles, etc. Casi seguro que el problema está por ahí.

Comment: voy a revisarlo entonces :D

Comment: Mirate como usar asyntask, runnables por aquí en SOES hay material

Comment: Efectivamente, tareas como consultas a BD o conexiones a internet son los típicos casos de lo que **NO** hay que hacer en el hilo principal ya que son muy susceptibles a demorarse y resultar en un ANR ( el mensaje que te sale). Te recomiendo que leas la documentación sobre [hilos y procesos](https://developer.android.com/guide/components/processes-and-threads.html) en la documentación de Android para poder descargar todas esas tareas a hilos secundarios. En particular pegale una mirada a [AsyncTask](https://developer.android.com/reference/android/os/AsyncTask.html) que debería simplificar much

Comment: por lo que he podido ver haces bastantes cargas de imágenes, yo me decantaría por hacer esa carga de imágenes en Asyntask y que se fueran cargando en segundo plano

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Yo probaría a extraer tu código de carga de las imágenes para que se cargaran en segundo plano.

Este es tu código:

```
    @Override
    public void onBindViewHolder(final MyViewHolder holder, final int position) {
        //Carga de imagen sin descargar archivo.
        Picasso p = Picasso.with(getActivity());
        p.setIndicatorsEnabled(true);
        /*Picasso.with(getActivity())*/
        p.load(listImgCat.get(position))
                .into(holder.imgViewCat, new Callback() {
                    @Override
                    public void onSuccess() {
                        //picassoLoad++;
                        if (picassoLoad == (listImgCat.size() - 1)) {
                            splashHomeLoad.setVisibility(View.GONE);
                            picassoLoad = 0;

                        }
                    }

                    @Override
                    public void onError() {

                    }
                });
```

Yo probaría a hacer algo como lo siguiente:

```
@Override
public void onBindViewHolder(final MyViewHolder holder, final int position) {
     try {
            holder.posicion = position;
            new CargaAsyncTask().execute(holder);
     }catch (Exception e){
            e.printStackTrace();
     }

     ....
 }
```

Por otra parte el AsynTask quedaría más o menos de la siguiente forma:

```
private class CargaAsyncTask extends AsyncTask<MyViewHolder, Void, MyViewHolder> {

            @Override
            protected MyViewHolder doInBackground(MyViewHolder... params) {
                //load image directly
                MyViewHolder viewHolder = params[0];
                try {
                    //Carga de imagen sin descargar archivo.
                    Picasso p = Picasso.with(getActivity());
                    p.setIndicatorsEnabled(true);

                    p.load(listImgCat.get(holder.posicion))
                     .into(holder.imgViewCat, new Callback() {
                           @Override
                           public void onSuccess() {
                               //picassoLoad++;
                               if (picassoLoad == (listImgCat.size() - 1)) {
                                    splashHomeLoad.setVisibility(View.GONE);
                                    picassoLoad = 0;
                               }
                           }

                           @Override
                           public void onError() {

                           }
                    });
                } catch (IOException e) {
                }
                return viewHolder;
            }
            @Override
            protected void onPostExecute(MyViewHolder result) {

            }
        }
```

Esto sería una aproximación porque no he trabajado nunca con la librería Picasso, pero estos pasos los utilice para cargar dinámicamente las imágenes en segundo plano en un Rss de noticias que hice en el que las imágenes se cargaban via URL.

Espero te sirva de ayuda.